# Issue with order elements stack when z-index value is not applied

Tags: html, css, dom

I have the following HTML structure

https://jsbin.com/yuqolejepo/edit?html,output

DIV `Box7_NEW_1438065416596` is positioned as first item in the DOM but in the rendered HTML is displayed visually under DIV `Box7`

For my understanding;

> Without any z-index value, elements stack in the order that they
>   appear in the DOM (the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level
>   appears on top). Elements with non-static positioning will always
>   appear on top of elements with default static positioning. [Source](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

Now considering that all my elements have a non-static positioning (`position:absolute`) why the lowest down DOM at the same hierarchy level
still appears visually positioned on top?

I found this part misleading:

> ...Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of
>   elements with default static positioning

Could you please provide me a clarification?

PS: I do not need to fix this issue usingz-index, I would need an explanation. Thanks.

```
 <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">
        <div class="Box" id="Box7_NEW_1438065416596" style="
                position: absolute;
                top: 240px;
                left: 40px;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;">
            <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Box" id="Box7d" style="
                position: absolute;
                top: 300px;
                left: 150px;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;">
            <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="Box" id="Box7" style="
                position: absolute;
                top: 200px;
                left: 0px;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;">
            <div data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
.Box {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: mediumspringgreen;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid green;
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

Comment: isn't `Box7` the lowest in DOM hierarchy ? this is why will be in top, followed by `Box7d` and then `Box7_NEW_1438065416596`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has the answer in it. "*the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top*".

[Stacking without z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

> When no element has a z-index, elements are stacked in this order (from bottom to top):

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and link, actually it helped me to clarified as reading my original source https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/ at point "Elements with non-static positioning will always appear on top of elements with default static positioning." was confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

"(the lowest one down at the same hierarchy level appears on top)"
Box7 is the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

Next blocks with the same z-index will always have bigger z-index, than the previous. That will be "virtual" z-index.

For Example:

- DIV 1 have z-index: 1 and it have normal z-index 1;
- DIV 2 have z-index: 1 but because prev have z-index 1, we got here z-index 1.2;
- DIV 3 have z-index: 1 but because prev have z-index 1.2, we got here z-index 1.3.

PS: This simple explanation without difficulties. Not by specification